# JOIN or Union of two tables - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I unite two select statement in one table result?

For instance in the first table I want to get everything however on my 2nd table I only want the corel name that is equal to the corel_id and id of my 2nd table?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM garage 
 UNION 
 SELECT c.name 
  FROM corel as c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM garage as g WHERE c.id = g.corel_id
```

I tried to execute this but this did not work. Is this right? or is there a better way to do this?

Sorry newbie here.

**UPDATE EXPECTED RESULT :**

https://anotepad.com/notes/b6662w

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih updated my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT g.*, c.name
FROM garage g
LEFT JOIN corel c
ON c.id = g.corel_id
```

Matching two tables in a database is called a **join**.  An inner join, the default, returns only the rows that match from both tables.

A left join returns all the rows from the first table whether or not they match the second, and any data from the second table that matches.  The right join does the inverse, returning only non-matching data from the second table.  There is also the full join that returns all data regardless of match.

Comment: @JonDobie Please add your table structure and sample data to the question.

Comment: @Jon Dobie: The query looks fine. If it returns no rows, then you either made a mistake or the table data is different from what you think it is. The garage table should have a foreign key on the corel_id to guarantee data consistency.

Comment: @JonDobie Also, I would like to mention that you should put this information in the question itself and not past a link, which is inconvenient and break later.

Answer (score 1):

A join statement is what you need. A join puts columns from multiple tables into rows together based in the matching conditions in the where clause.

A union requires 2 or more queries to have the same columns. The union puts the sets of rows together into a longer set or rows.